# button click does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

took this from the AngularJS tutorial [egghead.io](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope), it never seems to hit the logchore function:

```
app.controller("ChoreCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.logChore = function() {
            alert("is done");
        }
})
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/sFnAr/1/

Comment: this is not a directive. It's clearly a controller, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace ngclick="done()" to ng-click="done()"

```
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="chore">' + ' {{chore}}' + ' <div class="button" ng-click="done()">i m done</div>'
```

taken from the fiddle